# Disk compactness

Tags: general-topology, compactness

$$\mathring{D}_2 = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$$
Is this compact? What is an example of a open covering if it isn't compact? What does the dot on top of the Disk mean?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial.  The collection of sets $B_n=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2|x^2+y^2<1-\frac1n\}$ is an open cover without a finite subcover, so $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2|x^2+y^2<1\}$ is not compact

Comment: In general, $\mathring{X}$ means the interior of $X$, which has a number of equivalent formulations. In your case, $D_2$ is $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 | x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}$, and taking the interior will change the $\leq$ to $<$.

Answer (score 0):

JW Tanner points out how it is not compact. Please typeset questions with MathJax for future reference. The dot on top denotes "interior", a topological concept you can look up. The idea is that one generally denotes $D^2:= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}$. Then $\mathring{D^2}$ would then be as you define it, if you take the topological interior of $D^2$.